# Compress Node.js Response

Tags: node.js, express, compression

I want to compress the response on my node.js server. So the data transfers more fasts over the network.

Is there any middle ware for this? Which compress all my server response?

I am using express.js

Comment: you can use `zlib` module with stream

Answer (score 2):

i would rather use nginx to deal with compression in production. In case you still want to use node, check out http://npmjs.com/package/compression

Copy paste from the readme.

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.use(compression())
```

Comment: How nginx will do it? It will by default compress the response?

Comment: You will need to enable gzip. Check out https://davidwalsh.name/enable-gzip